# Cakephp 3 & Ajax, send $.get additional data

Tags: json, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I try to send custom data using $.get from jquery but cakephp 3 does not recognize the variables.

Here is my function in controller:

```
public function view($cat,$id,$page){
        $comments = $this->Comments->find('all')->where(['category =' => $cat, 'AND' => ['category_id =' => $id]])->order(['comments.created' => 'DESC'])
                        ->contain([
                            'Reports' => function($q){return $q->where(['user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);},
                            'Chars' => function($q){ return $q->select(['id','name','class','race','level','guild_id', 'user_id'])
                            ->contain(['Guilds' => function($q){ return $q->select(['id','name']);
                            }]);
                        }])->limit(3)->page($page);
if($cat == 'Videos'){
                $subject = $this->Comments->Videos->get($id);
            }
            $category = $cat;
            $this->set(compact('subject','comments','category'));
    }
}
```

And here's the .js

```
$('.more').click(function(){

    $.get($(this).attr('href'),{cat:'Videos',id:'44',page:'2',function(data){
        $('.coms').empty().append(data);
    });
    return false;

});
```

And the link:

```
<?= $this->Html->link('More', ['controller' => 'Comments','action' => 'view'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary more']) ?>
```

The fix values in the .js is for the test, it works if I send the data in the link with $.get(href) but I want to know how to pass custom data in the $.get request.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

Hi, I did a little api to get the data I need from a json array.

So I created an ApiController to do all the ajax requests I need. Here is test example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ApiController extends AppController
{
    public function test($id)
    {
        $UsersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $users = $UsersTable->find()->where(['id <' => $id]);
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
}
?>
```

I want to get the list of all my users from an ajax call (that's the worst idea ever but it's just for the test ;))

Now I need to enable json for this view. For this, I need to go in config/routes.php to add this:

```
Router::scope('/api', function($routes){
  $routes->extensions(['json']);
  $routes->connect('/test/*', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'test', '_ext' => 'json']);
});
```

Now when I go on http://localhost/mywebsite/api/test/100, I have a json array of all the users with an id < 100, ready to get pulled by an ajax script.

```
'_ext' => 'json'
```

means you don't have to go on api/test.json to display the json array

Now on a random view in a random controller, I put a button to try all this and I call my javascript file to do my ajax request.

```
<button class="test">Test button</button>
<?= $this->Html->script('test', ['block' => true]) ?>
```

Now in my test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var value = 100;
  $('.test').click(function(){
    $.get('/api/test/' + value, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

I click the button and the log shows an array with all the users I wanted in my console when I push F12 (on chrome).

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP doesn't magically map query string parameters to method arguments, that's not even supported by routes.

You can access query string paramters via the request object

```
$this->request->query('cat');
```

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters**